# Why are my objects keep multiplying and making a path in gamemaker?

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-studio-2

I am new to GMS2 and was coding up a game when this happened:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8Wo3.png)

It would be of great help if anyone could help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it's not objects that are multiplying, but that you don't have a background in your room, so whatever was drawn during the last frame stays there.

Comment: Me when I saw that comment "Yeah, that doesn't make sense." When I did that "What?! That actually worked?" Anyways, thanks!